# Why am I getting TypeError when adding a property to an Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I am trying to add a property on an Observable after subscribing and assigning the response in my Angular 4 app.

```
getCourses() {
  return this.coursesService.getCourses().subscribe(
    res => {
      this.courses = res;
      for (const course of this.courses) {
        course.isChecked = false;
      }
    }
  );
}
```

The code works and creates the property on the Observable but I get the error below as well.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot create property 'isChecked' on boolean 'false' at SafeSubscriber._next at SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub
```

How can I correct the code so that I don't get errors?

Solved!!!

So I didn't realize that at the end of the array of objects that the api was returning was false.

[{ "PersonID": "129", "FirstName": "Ash", "MiddleName": "E.", "LastName": "Green", "MemberID": "129346", "MemberNumber": "105", "MemberStatus": 2, "AffiliatedAgencyID": "160" }, { "PersonID": "221334", "FirstName": "Abs", "MiddleName": null, "LastName": "Plast", "MemberID": "1953", "MemberNumber": "2047", "MemberStatus": 1, "AffiliatedAgencyID": "13" }, false]

Once I created an if statement to account for the false at the end, my problem was fixed. The other object I was getting doesn't have this anomaly. So it wasn't happening.

Comment: What is `res`? Can you log it? Where is it coming from?

Comment: Remove the `const` keyword if you intend to change `course`

Comment: Couses is from an api that returns a json.   [{
    "PersonID": "129",
    "FirstName": "Ash",
    "MiddleName": "E.",
    "LastName": "Green",
    "MemberID": "129346",
    "MemberNumber": "105",
    "MemberStatus": 2,
    "AffiliatedAgencyID": "160"
  },
  {
    "PersonID": "221334",
    "FirstName": "Abs",
    "MiddleName": null,
    "LastName": "Plast",
    "MemberID": "1953",
    "MemberNumber": "2047",
    "MemberStatus": 1,
    "AffiliatedAgencyID": "13"
  }]

Comment: I tried removing const and it didn't change the error.

Comment: @PhillipThomas that's no needed. He is not re-asigning course, is just update a property of it. You can see how `const` work here https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/const

Answer (score 2):

If `res` is an array, you should be able to go trough it without any problem. But make sure that `res` is an array.

```
getCourses() {
  return this.coursesService.getCourses()
    .subscribe(res => this.courses = res.map(course => course.isChecked = false));
}
```

Comment: It is an array of Couses from an api that returns a json. I have another place that I am doing the same thing but not getting the error. The original object doesn't have a isCheck property.

Comment: I changed the function to match yours and I get an error that says "Property map doesn't exist on type Object."

Comment: Ok, that means that `res` is not an array, it's an Object!

Comment: Update the question and add the code from the service, that will give us more information

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't realize that at the end of the array of objects that the api was returning was false.

[{ "PersonID": "129", "FirstName": "Ash", "MiddleName": "E.", "LastName": "Green", "MemberID": "129346", "MemberNumber": "105", "MemberStatus": 2, "AffiliatedAgencyID": "160" }, { "PersonID": "221334", "FirstName": "Abs", "MiddleName": null, "LastName": "Plast", "MemberID": "1953", "MemberNumber": "2047", "MemberStatus": 1, "AffiliatedAgencyID": "13" }, false]

Once I created an if statement to account for the false at the end, my problem was fixed. The other object I was getting doesn't have this anomaly. So it wasn't happening.